# Execute wp_after_insert_post after the permalink is customized

Tags: php, functions, permalinks, actions

I'm trying to set a meta property to a new post's permalink using update_post_meta. When I run this on wp_after_insert_post I get a permalink that ends in "?p=[ID]". If I update the post to run the function again the permalink is updated to something that ends in, "/[category]/[post-name-slug]/" which is what I want to insert originally.

How can I delay update_post_meta until the permalink is resolved? I was thinking of using add_action/do_action to delay when I call update_post_meta but I'm using the post ID to get the permalink in the function. Any recommendations?

Here's my current code:

```
add_action('wp_after_insert_post', 'add_permalink_to_new_post', 0, 4);

function add_permalink_to_new_post( $post_id, $post, $update, $post_before ) {

    // Only run this on a newly created post
    if (!empty($post_before)) {
        return;
    }
    
    update_post_meta( $post_id, 'canonical_permalink', (string) get_permalink($post_id) );
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To execute `update_post_meta` after the permalink is customized, you can use the `save_post` hook instead of `wp_after_insert_post`. Here's how you can modify your code:

```php
add_action('save_post', 'add_permalink_to_new_post', 10, 2);

function add_permalink_to_new_post($post_id, $post) {

    // Check if this is a new post
    if ($post->post_date_gmt == $post->post_modified_gmt) {
        // Only run this on a newly created post
        update_post_meta($post_id, 'canonical_permalink', get_permalink($post_id));
    }
}
```

In the updated code:

1. I've changed the hook to `save_post`, which fires after a post is saved or updated.
2. Inside the `add_permalink_to_new_post` function, we check if the `post_date_gmt` and `post_modified_gmt` are the same. If they are, it means that the post is newly created, as the modification date hasn't been updated yet.
3. If it's a newly created post, we update the `canonical_permalink` post meta with the customized permalink using `get_permalink($post_id)`.

This way, the `update_post_meta` function will only be called after the permalink is customized for a newly created post, ensuring that you get the permalink you want without any issues with `?p=[ID]`. You can now use this updated code in your WordPress theme or plugin to achieve the desired functionality.

Comment: Nice! I'm actually trying to update the Yoast canonical and unfortunately using save_post alone didn't do the trick. I had to use save_post to fetch the canonical and wp_after_insert_post to update the meta property. For some reason Yoast would overwrite the permalink with the ID version if I just used the save_post hook. Between both of those functions the code is working now. Thank you!

Comment: Excellent! I'm glad this helped get you to a resolution 